# Amazon SES bounce messages don't seem to be properly categorized as Spam, Syntax, Invalid, etc

Tags: civimail, bounce, amazon-ses, spam

We have Amazon SES set up as a mailer, which works great and cuts our mailing costs to negligible levels. The only issue is that the bounce messages don't seem to be getting properly categorized by CiviCRM and I'm not sure how to address this.

Messages that should be marked Spam are categorized as Syntax, messages that are just format warnings ("This message is in MIME format.") are being categorized as Spam, etc. Obviously, this causes emails to be put on hold that shouldn't be or vice versa.

Not having much idea how this works, I'm not sure how to go about addressing it. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Seems the problem is not specific to Amazon SES (except the "abuse report" term that Amazon uses was added in 4.7.30 and we are on an older version). Other mis-categorizations are just CiviCRM. Also useful to know that Syntax is the fallback category.
Here's where the categorization happens:

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/xml/templates/civicrm_data.tpl#L1233